# Can/Should I define a schema for a requests call using pydantic?

Tags: python, python-requests, pydantic

I am writing a class to handle get/post/patch/delete requests to an API. For this, I am writing a method each (e.g. `def get_request()`). The parameters needed for the requests are quite a few, which would result in a long list of parameters for each function. Therefore I want to define the schema in some other way and pass it as a single variable.

Of course I could do this using a regular dict, but since I am using pydantic anyhow to parse the return of the request, I was wondering if I could (and should) use a pydantic model to pass the parameters to the request. Is there a "pythonic way" to handle these kind of functions?

In result, the code may look something like this (didn't test this code):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
import requests

class Params(BaseModel):
  param_1: str
  param_2: int
  param_3: list[str]

class ApiCall:
  def get_request(self, url: str, params: Params):
    response = requests.get(url, params = params.dict())
```

Is this a valid way to handle this kind of thing? Or is there a different, usual way to handle this kind of situation?

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on what web/HTTP framework you are using. Pydantic is data validation library and can be quite useful without any network calls. If you use FastAPI, you might want to take a look at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#advantages-of-annotated

Comment: It's for a client using the requests library, I won't combine this with a web framework.

Comment: My bad, in that case it's hard to say. You get extra validations with pydantic, albeit you could just use `TypedDict` for most simple requests usage, while getting benefits provided by mypy. But even that depends how you build up requests params. Pydantic is great though if you need to do more thorough checking than vanilla types